# what is the use of outer join as it combines all the records from both the tables?

Tags: sql

what is the use of outer join as it combines all the records from both the tables?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've used it in the past is to return data from two tables that don't have matching records in the other.

An example would be that you own two restaurants, you want to find a list of all customers that dine at one restaurant but not the other so that you can do some targeted marketing or similar.

Or say you have two tables, parent and child. One outer join would allow you to find all parents without a record in the child table and vice versa.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp